# How to add text in center bottom of screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, alignment

I am having a column contains some widget(picture below) and I'm trying to center the text(Don't have account sign up) between the button above it and the bottom of the screen. Any solution would be appreciated, thanks
[This is what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG1HE.png) and [this is my result so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yWO6.png)

Here is my code so far:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    const Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        "or",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD9D9D9), shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
            child: Text(
              "Continue",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          )),
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ),
    const Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Text(
        "Don’ have an account? Sign up",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Color(0x80000000)),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: From your current snippet, it seems on center. If you are using Column with having scrollable  widget on top, `Spacer` widget can help

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately the text is currently lied right below to the button above it and I am trying to build it like the image.

Comment: @Tuân can you post full screen code, i will answer your question

Comment: Hi @Quicklearner, the full screen code is just like that with some more text widget above

Answer (score 0):

Try this use `Spacer` above the text Dont have an account ? Sign up?  and give some space using `SizedBox` under it and use container to align it in center like this

Dont know if this is what you want..

```
  Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      const Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          "or",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
              child: Text(
                "Continue",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
              ),
            )),
      ),
      Spacer(),
         Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            "Don’ have an account? Sign up",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Color(0x80000000)),
          ),
        ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      )
    ],
  ),
```